# Green's function of simple random walk is defined on $Z^d, d=3,4,….$

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-walk, greens-function

I want to ask why the Green's function of simple random walk is defined on $\Bbb Z^d$, $d=3,4,\dots$.

Let $S_n$ be the position of the walker at time $n$.

The Green's function is defined to be $$G(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(S_n=y|S_o=x)$$

$x,y \in \Bbb Z^d$.

My attempt:

Let $\tau_y = \min \{n : S_n=y\}$.

For $n>\tau_y$,

$$P(S_n=y|S_o=x)=P(S_n=y,S_{\tau_y}=y|S_o=x)=P(S_n=y|S_{\tau_y}=y)P(S_{\tau_y}=y|S_o=x)=P(S_n=y|S_{\tau_y}=y)P(\tau_y<\infty|S_0=x).$$

We have $$G(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(S_n=y|S_o=x)=P(\tau_y<\infty|S_0=x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(S_n=y|S_{\tau_y}=y)=P(\tau_y<\infty|S_0=x)G(y,y)<\infty$$ since when $d=3,4,\dots$, $G(y,y)<\infty$.

I'm not quite sure whether I have missed someting, appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: I'm sorry for writing a bad comment earlier : are you allowed to assume that $G(y,y) < \infty$ for all $y$ and $d=3,4,...$? You seem to use this in the second last line, but that's actually quite difficult to prove by itself.

Comment: oh yes, I know how to prove it.